# Is there way we could determine the usage of TFS Extensions in our organisation?

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

We are using TFS 2018 (2018.1 to be precise). I need to find out how many projects are using a particular TFS Extension. How can I get this information? Few of these extensions are installed through Visual Studio Market Place and few are developed internally.

Comment: Hi Potatojaisiladki, do you still have any concern on this. It's not able to list such kind of info. Just checking to see if the information provided was helpful. If my reply helped or gave a right direction. Appreciate for marking it as an answer,  which will also helps others in the community.

Comment: Hi Patrick- I am sorry I couldn't come back to you on this sooner. I have already gone through the links provided by you. But that's not what I am looking for. What I am looking for is to find out the number of builds or projets using a particular TFS extension. However, thank you for your help.

Comment: Hi Potatojaisiladki Thanks for your kindly update. Sorry for not make it more clearly. What you are looking is not available at present. There's no such build-in feature. You could submit a feature request in [Azure DevOps Develop Community site](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/21/visual-studio-team-services.html?type=idea). Our PM will kindly review your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, when you install a extension, you need to specify a collection, the extension will be installed for all team projects under this collection.

In other words, **extensions are installed into the collection level**, it's not able to use extension for a specific project. All projects in the collection are installed.

You could take a look at our official link here: [Install extensions for on-premises servers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/marketplace/get-tfs-extensions?view=azure-devops-2019)

For now, only with for a paid extension, you can restrict who can access it by [Assigning paid extension access to users](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/marketplace/install-extension?view=azure-devops).

---

Update

However, to find out the number of builds or projects using a particular TFS extension is not available at present.  There's no such build-in feature.

You could submit a feature request in [Azure DevOps Develop Community site](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/21/visual-studio-team-services.html?type=idea). 
Our PM will kindly review your suggestion.